# Calculating the average increase from array values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, average

I need to calculate the average increase of array values, and I've made a little script which works, but I'd like to know if:

1. There is a better, more efficient way of doing this
2. My logic is correct here in calculating the average increase

Lets say I have an array like so:

```
$array = array(5,10,15,10,0,15);
```

Lets also imagine that each array item is 1 day, and the value is some counter for that day. I would like to calculate the average increase/decrease in the counter.

What I've done, is looped through the array, and altered the values so that the current item = current item - previous item, what way I'm left with an array which would look like so:

```
$array = array(5,5,-5,-10,15);
```

Then I calculate the average as per normal, which in this example would give me a 2 average increase on a daily basis.

Code here:

```
$array = array(5,10,15,10,0,15);
$count = count($array);

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    if($i==0) {
        $value = $array[$i];
        unset($array[$i]);
    }
    else {
        $tmp = $array[$i];
        $array[$i] -= $value;
        $value = $tmp;
    }
}

echo array_sum($array) / count($array);
```

Is the logic correct here, and is there a more efficient way of doing this, maybe without the loop?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Updated code to account for excluding first value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
function moving_average($array) {

for ($i = 1; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    $result[] = $array[$i] - $array[$i-1];
}

return array_sum($result)/count($result);
}
```

Comment: That works well too, a much neater version of my original loop, thank you!

Comment: Some testing shows that this is the fastest method, so thank you. If I could flag your answer as the answer I would, but I really dig the snazziness of @silkfire's answer

Comment: so, you're willing to give up speed in favor of a one-liner? ;-)

Comment: You're making me feel bad. I'd always go for speed, and will be using your code, so I guess the answer should go to you?

Comment: May I edit your answer to show the exact function I will be doing with? (I added some error checking etc)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$array       = array(5,10,15,10,0,15);
$array2      = $array;

array_pop($array2);
array_unshift($array2, $array[0]);
$subtracted  = array_map(function ($x, $y) { return $y-$x; } , $array2, $array);
array_shift($subtracted); /// Comment this if you want six values with 0 as first value

echo array_sum($subtracted) / count($subtracted);
```

Comment: Works very well, will benchmark this against @silkfire answer and see which one is more efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snazzy one-liner for you:

```
$days = array(5, 10, 15, 10, 0, 15);

$deltas = array_slice(array_map(function($day1, $day2) {
    return $day2 - $day1;
}, $days, array_slice($days, 1)), 0, -1);

var_dump(array_sum($deltas) / count($deltas));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(5,10,15,10,0,15);
list($prevVal) = array_slice($array, 1);

array_walk($array, function($value, $key, &$prevVal)  use(&$array){
    if ($key==0) { return; }
    $array[$key] = ($value - $prevVal);
    $prevVal = $value;
}, $prevVal);

echo array_sum($array) / count($array);
```

Outputs 1.6666666666667 in float(3.0994415283203E-5)