# Get average difference between all unique rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bantracker which logs to MySQL each ban, I would like to get the average difference between each unix time so I can estimate based on the data when the next ban will happen.

My thinking would be Last entry + average? Maybe I am completely wrong and somebody has a better idea.

The Table structure looks like this: [image]

Each apikey is unique.

Any help / ideas are much appreciated I don't mind if it's a MySQL query or PHP code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to calculate a moving average:

```
function moving_average( $array ) {

  $z = sizeof( $array );

  for ( $i = 1; $i < $z; $i++ ) {
    $result[] = $array[ $i ] - $array[ $i-1 ];
  }

  return array_sum( $result ) / count( $result );

}
```

Hat tip to: [Calculating the average increase from array values in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272851/calculating-the-average-increase-from-array-values-in-php)

Comment: @SM9 Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use(COUNT,SUM) to find average

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(time) as count,SUM(time) as sum,MAX(time) as sum FROM table_name";

$avg=$row["sum"]/$row["count"];
```

Comment: Currently I am looping all entries then pushing into an array then running the moving_average php function on the array Your method works too :)